# How can I insert a set of pages into all existing documents within an existing batch in Kofax Capture

Tags: copy, document, capture, kofax

We are using Kofax Capture 11.1

I have a use case where a business unit will give us 2 stacks of paper:

Stack 1: Single page cover sheets printed from accounting software with all required index values that will be processed with zonal recognition. Anywhere from 50-200 of these at a time.

Stack 2: A 50-100 page document that is the supporting documentation that covers each/all of the items in stack one.

I'm trying to reduce manual work by having users scan Stack 1 and do the separation into the 50-200 individual documents within the batch. THEN, I want them to be able to scan the second document and have it automatically inserted into or associated with each of those original documents in the batch without having to scan it for each document or manually copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0):

The base idea is to have those cover sheets inserted before the actual document.
So take the page from stack one and put it before the beginning of the document in stack 2.

Continue the preparation for all other documents.
If you setup you separation correctly to coversheet. Then everything should be done automatically. (most cases you can even choose if you want your cover-sheet to be exported with the actual document)

If you are stuck on having to scan the stack one as a complete and then do stack 2.
Then you should look into foldering options in Kofax Capture. 
Documents will be sorted as you want, but they will still be exported as separate documents. (You can alternatively merge them with custom module or custom export)

Comment: Rene, thanks for you answer. The issue here is that there is not a 1 to 1 relationship between the "cover sheet" and the document. Each of the cover sheets needs to include the entire second stack of pages. So, if stack 1 had 50 cover sheets and stack 2 was a 75 page document, there would be 50 documents of 76 pages each when all is said and done, if that makes sense.

Comment: In that case i think you should go with a custom module to merge and copy the images to your rule. However I'm not sure how the licenses would go in such a case.

Comment: Thanks Rene. I think we’re going to go with a custom module at this point. Appreciate your insight.